# Mathematical Statistics Question

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

It is known that $X$ has a $b(Y,p)$ distribution, where $Y$ is a random variable which has a $P(λ)$. Find the moment generating function of $X$.
--I know that the MGF of a random variable is $E[e^{tX}]$, but the second random variable inside is throwing me off.

Comment: The [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) is actually $M_X(t)=E\left[e^{tX}\right]$

Comment: Ah I see I put down the wrong thing. Thanks! Corrected it. It's mainly the distributions and joint stuff that's frustrating me.

Comment: Asking questions without personal input is a big "no" on this site. Asking three unrelated questions in the same post is also to be avoided.

Comment: If I had more personal insight I would have said it. I put a little bit of my thought at the end of each problem.

Comment: If the problem is your book, maybe you should try another book. There are many many many books out there that tackle these issues.

Comment: @user395073   Too many questions, and too little contribution from you.

Comment: @amWhy If I had more to contribute I'd be more than happy to do so. I wrote a bit of what I thought for each of the 3. If I knew more I would put more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$$\#1$ is a standard exercise. It ought to be phased as $X\mid Y \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(Y,p),$ i.e. the **conditional** distribution of $X$ **given** $Y$ is $\operatorname{Binomial}(Y,p),$ rather than that that is simply the distribution of $X$. The distribution of $X$, i.e. the *marginal* (i.e. "unconditional") distribution of $X$, is supported on the infinite set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\},$ as a moment's thought will tell you.
\begin{align}
\Pr(X=x) = \E(\Pr(X=x\mid Y))  {} & = \sum_{y = 0}^\infty \Pr(X=x\mid Y=y) \Pr(Y=y) \\[10pt]
= {} & \sum_{y=x} ^\infty \Pr(X=x\mid Y=y) \Pr(Y=y) \tag a \\[6pt]
& \quad (\text{This starts at } y=x \text{ rather than at } y=0 \\
& \quad \phantom{(} \text{because } X \text{ cannot be equal to } x \text{ unless } y\ge x.)
\end{align}

You know that $\displaystyle\Pr(Y=y) = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^y}{y!}.$

And that $\displaystyle \Pr(X=x \mid Y=y) = \binom y x p^x (1-p)^{y-x}.$

Plugging those in to line $(\textbf{a})$ above, we get.
$$
\sum_{y=x}^\infty \binom y x p^x (1-p)^{y-x} \cdot \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^y}{y!}.
$$
If we let $w=y-x$, then as $y$ goes from $x$ to $\infty$, then $w$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, and where we see $y-x$ we put $w$, and where we see $y$ alone we put $w+x$, getting
$$
\sum_{w=0}^\infty \binom {w+x} x p^x (1-p)^w \cdot \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{w+x}}{(w+x)!}.
$$
This is
\begin{align}
\sum_{w=0}^\infty \frac{(w+x)!}{w!x!} p^x (1-p)^w \cdot \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{w+x}}{(w+x)!} = \sum_{w=0}^\infty \left( \frac{(p\lambda)^x}{x!} e^{-p\lambda} \right) \left(\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^w}{w!} e^{-(1-p)\lambda} \right).
\end{align}
The factor $\displaystyle \left( \frac{(p\lambda)^x}{x!} e^{-p\lambda} \right)$ does not change as $w$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, so it can be pulled out, getting
$$
\left( \frac{(p\lambda)^x}{x!} e^{-p\lambda} \right) \sum_{w=0}^\infty  \left(\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^w}{w!} e^{-(1-p)\lambda} \right).
$$
The sum is clearly equal to $1$ (since it's the sum of all the probabilities from the $\operatorname{Poisson}((1-p)\lambda)$ distribution). So finally we have
$$
\Pr(X=x) = \frac{(p\lambda)^x}{x!} e^{-p\lambda},
$$
or in other words
$$
X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(p\lambda).
$$

**PS:** The question has been revised. What I did above should do it if you know the mfg of the Poisson distribution, but here's a way that is more in the spirit of the way the question is phrased:
\begin{align}
\E(e^{tX}) & = \E(\E(e^{tX}\mid Y)) = \E( (1 - p + pe^t)^Y) \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{y=0}^\infty (1-p+pe^t)^y \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^y}{y!} = e^{-\lambda} \sum_{y=0}^\infty \frac{ \left( (1-p+pe^t) \lambda \right)^y }{y!} \\[10pt]
& = e^{-\lambda} e^{-(1-p+pe^t) \lambda }.
\end{align}
Use a bit of algebra and see if you can get that to look like the mgf of the Poisson distribution with expected value $p\lambda$.

Comment: I was simply suggesting that you end with something to the sort:  "Now, the ball's in your court. Consider how you might use this answer in order to start tackling  #2, #3. and\or etc."  At any rate, you clearly knew, at the time of your reply ro me, #2, #3. have been retracted by the OP.  So, why the need to reply to me when my comment no longer applies, which you know. Good luck in your effort to reopen a poor question, which happens to be a question you answered...

Comment: @amWhy I retracted it to avoid having more than 1 in a post. Why are you attacking him for helping? I for one sincerely appreciate what he wrote.

Comment: user395073: I am not attacking @Michael.  Your retraction was a very good idea.  He knows the consequences of answering only part of a question, and worse, a question that is originally too broad and without context. Some of us choose to invest our time into answering questions for which the asker has posted a question showing that the asker has invested time, rather than simply dumping a question(s), like you did. Here, you got an answer to a question to lessen your assignment load, in exchange for a green checkmark, and the 15 reputation points it gives him,

Comment: Unfortunately, your behavior is thus rewarded, and it's likely you'll post another "drive-through-order-for-an answer".

Comment: Behavior? Justly rewarded? I got the explanation I needed and now comprehend the problem. Is that not the goal? Just because YOU don't like it you don't have to come in here with your butt buddy Did and try to sabotage things. Michael had no "consequences" there. He did a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

The random variable $X$ may be viewed as 
$$X = \sum_{k=1}^Y B_k$$
where $B_k$ are iid Bernoulli random variables.
Then the PGF of X is given by
$$P_X(s)=G_Y(H_B(s))$$
where $G(\cdot)$ is the PGF of Poisson Distribution and $H(\cdot)$ is the PGF of Bernoulli distribution.
\begin{eqnarray*}
P_X(s)&=&\exp(\lambda((1-p)+ps-1))\\
&=&\exp(\lambda p(s-1))
\end{eqnarray*}
which is the PGF of Poisson Distribution with parameter $\lambda p$.